# Points rotate oddly, what's wrong with my calculations?

Tags: c, opengl, rotation, glsl, trigonometry

This is what I want to get:
[image: rotating square]

And this is what I get:

[image: Wrongly rotating triangle]

When I'm using this formulae:

[image: formualae]

Or, more precisely, this GLSL vertex shader code:

```
#version 330
layout (location = 0) in vec2 pos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 clr;
uniform float sinr, cosr;
float x, y;
out vec3 color;
void main() {
    color = clr;
    x = pos.x * cosr - pos.y * sinr;
    y = pos.x * sinr + pos.y * cosr;
    gl_Position = vec4(x, y, 0.0, 1.0); }
```

I'm out of ideas. I did my math and my code should rotate correctly but obviously it doesn't. Could anyone tell me why and how to fix it?

Edit: set/update routines:

```
void tgle_rot(int i, float rad) {
    float *sin = &global.objs[i].sinr, *cos = &global.objs[i].cosr;
    *sin = *sin * cosf(rad) + *cos * sinf(rad);
    *cos = *cos * cosf(rad) - *sin * sinf(rad); }

void callback(void) {
    tgle_rot(0, 0.01); }

static void run_draw(void) {
    /* ... */
    for(int i = 0; i < global.num_objs; ++i) {
        /* ... */
        glUniform1f(global.shader.sinr, global.objs[i].sinr);
        glUniform1f(global.shader.cosr, global.objs[i].cosr);
        /* ... */ }
    /* ... */
    glfwSwapBuffers(global.window); }
```

Edit 2: the problem doesn't lie within `tgle_rot`! I've changed it to

```
void tgle_rot(int i, float rad) {
    float *sin = &global.objs[i].sinr, *cos = &global.objs[i].cosr;
    static float rotation = 0;
    rotation += 0.01;
    *sin = sinf(rotation);
    *cos = cosf(rotation); }
```

and the program behavior didn't change!

Edit 3: here's the rotation with single line:

[image: line rot]

Solution: it turns out the problem was the order of transformations. I was scaling first and THEN rotating. Swapping scaling and rotation fixed the problem. I didn't add the scaling part because I thought it wasn't important to the question. It turns out I was mistaken. Now I'm figuring out why. Thank you for your time, I will change my `tgle_rot` function according to your suggestions.

ACTUALLY, NO. THE PROBLEM WAS IT THE **SHADER**.

```
void main() {
        color = clr;
        x = x * cosr - y * sinr;
        y = x * sinr + y * cosr; // using modified x!!!
        gl_Position = vec4(x, y, 0.0, 1.0);
```

Comment: You need to study about axes of rotation I don't know but it seems like it's related to [*Euler Angles*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles).

Comment: it's not clear what you want to achieve. Do you want to rotate the object or the view? Where do you set and update `sinr` and `cosr`?

Comment: I want to achieve the exact same rotation as in the first picture - I want to rotate each point of the object. I am updating the code to include the set/update routines.

Comment: Be clear: what is odd about the first animation?

Comment: There is **nothing** odd with the **first** animation - the **square** rotates **perfectly** fine. However, the **second** animation is **odd** - the lines of **triangle** change their distance from the origin of axis plain.

Comment: I don't think the formula is the problem, it's simple enough and seems correct to me. Maybe you have a 2D/3D configuration problem, projection_matrix, model_matrix, data issues. The orbit of the green corner point seems to be a triangle, and the red/blue ones??

Comment: Is tgle_rot really correct?  Should you be using the new value of *sin in the computation of *cos?  Maybe you should use temporary variables.

Comment: You should use temporary variables. You compute a new `*sin` but the next line computing `*cos` is using the new value of `*sin`

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you, now I noticed it and corrected it.

Comment: @WeatherVane I could upvote yours if you posted it.

Comment: @WeatherVane Actually, the problem was not the function, but the shader code. It's the same kind of bug, though :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a guess, because I can't try it out, but change...

```
void tgle_rot(int i, float rad) {
    float *sin = &global.objs[i].sinr, *cos = &global.objs[i].cosr;
    *sin = *sin * cosf(rad) + *cos * sinf(rad);
    *cos = *cos * cosf(rad) - *sin * sinf(rad); }
```

to ...

```
void tgle_rot(int i, float rad) {
    float *sin = &global.objs[i].sinr, *cos = &global.objs[i].cosr;
    float tmpSin = *sin, tmpCos = *cos;
    *sin = tmpSin * cosf(rad) + tmpCos * sinf(rad);
    *cos = tmpCos * cosf(rad) - tmpSin * sinf(rad); }
```

You are using a modified Sin in the Cos computation, so temp variables avoids that.

Answer (score 1):

In this function

```
void tgle_rot(int i, float rad) {
    float *sin = &global.objs[i].sinr, *cos = &global.objs[i].cosr;
    *sin = *sin * cosf(rad) + *cos * sinf(rad);
    *cos = *cos * cosf(rad) - *sin * sinf(rad);
}
```

you compute new values for `*sin` and `*cos`. However the `*cos` calculation is using the new value of `*sin` instead of its original value. I would do it like this, using temporary variables:

```
void tgle_rot(int i, float rad) {
    float *sin = &global.objs[i].sinr, *cos = &global.objs[i].cosr;
    float sindash, cosdash;
    sindash = *sin * cosf(rad) + *cos * sinf(rad);
    cosdash = *cos * cosf(rad) - *sin * sinf(rad);
    *sin = sindash;
    *cos = cosdash;
}
```